# Выбранный объект Drag and Drop

Tags: android, drag-n-drop

Изучаю Drag and drop в Android. Конечно же из [первоисточника](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html).
Вопрос возник сразу, почему при перетаскивании одного элемента (DraggableDot.java), при этом появляется зеленная "обводка", эта "обводка" появляется на всех элементах данного типа и на те, которые я не перетаскиваю.

Это особенность данного примера? или drag'n'dropa?

Пример брал из \andriod-sdks\samples\android-хх\ApiDemos\ файлы DraggableDot.java и DragAndDropDemo.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это особенность данной реализации, вы можете сделать по-другому. Только в примере ApiDemos перетыскиваемый объект не имеет обводку, остальные имеют зелено-белую обводку, а тот объект, над которым происходит перетаскивание - белый. Вся суть заключается в этих строчках:

```
if (mDragInProgress && mAcceptsDrag) {
    // Обводка состоит из NUM_GLOW_STEP*2 (20 штук) колец
    for (int i = NUM_GLOW_STEPS; i > 0; i--) {
        // mHovering = true - если над объектом происходит перетаскивание
        int color = (mHovering) ? WHITE_STEP : GREEN_STEP;
        // Здесь в зависимости от i плавный переход от цвета color к белому(#FFFFFFFF)
        color = i*(color | ALPHA_STEP);
        mGlow.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, rad, mGlow);
        rad -= 0.5f;
        canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, rad, mGlow);
        rad -= 0.5f;
    }
}
```

Где:

```
int NUM_GLOW_STEPS = 10;
int GREEN_STEP = 0x0000FF00 / NUM_GLOW_STEPS;
int WHITE_STEP = 0x00FFFFFF / NUM_GLOW_STEPS;
int ALPHA_STEP = 0xFF000000 / NUM_GLOW_STEPS;
```

Answer (score 0):

Наверное, дело в этом

```
v.setColorFilter(Color.GREEN);
```

(см.  `myDragEventListener.onDrag()` )

Comment: а где вы это нашли?

Comment: ctrl+F - и у тебя тоже получится

Comment: geek, v.setColorFilter(Color.GREEN); в файлах DraggableDot.java и DragAndDropDemo.java нет.

Gorets, вы бы лучше по теме что-нибудь сказали.

Comment: по ссылке на "первоисточник" - см. "Responding to drag events: an example"